# Error in GWT(web application project)?

Tags: gwt

i created one web application project.I try to run the project but it shows the following output.How to solve this?

---

### There is a new version of the SDK available.

Latest SDK:
Release: 1.3.1
Timestamp: Tue Feb 09 04:30:41 IST 2010
API versions: [1.0]

---

Your SDK:
Release: 1.3.0
Timestamp: Tue Dec 15 00:17:37 IST 2009
API versions: [1.0]

---

Please visit http://code.google.com/appengine for the latest SDK.

---

The server is running at http://localhost:8888/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already started a server running your GWT application (or just any other server), which you will have to stop before you can start another one.  Or do like Igor said and start your GWT server on another port.

Answer (score 3):

It probably means that port 8888 is already in use by some other service (Java server?) - if you're using Google Eclipse Plugin, you can specify the port in the project settings, otherwise use the `--port` parameter.